# No component scan using XmlBeanDefinitionReader

Tags: spring

I am loading my beans using :

```
 XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(beanDefinitionRegistry);

 reader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_XSD);

 reader.loadBeanDefinitions(resource);

 ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).refresh();
```

will it do the component scan also ? Do i need to use the ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser ? Cannot find it anywhere in documentation or in the SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think the link might help:  [programcreek](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=xbpm5-master/activiti-engine/src/main/java/org/activiti/engine/impl/cfg/BeansConfigurationHelper.java)

Comment: It doesnot work for me . The component scan is not working and not loading beans in the context